# Mysql foreign key view

Tags: mysql

is there any command to find out all the foreign keys in a table in Mysql and the parent tables that it references ?

I am using MySql version 3.23.54a-11

Comment: I misread your version number in your question and thought I saw a 5.x where there was none. I don't know how to retrieve that metadata from 3.x, if it is possible.

Comment: ok...then there is something else that you may perhaps help me with. i have installed rhl 9 on vmware workstation ace edition. on this rhl 9 i have mysql 3.23.54a-11. i would like to upgrade this mysql3.23.54a-11 to mysql 5.0. can you suggest a way of doing this step by step. i am unable to connect to the internet using my rhl 9 running on VMware. is there a way to download the rpm for mysql 5.0 and then simply upgrade by installing that rpm package...?

Answer (score 1):

**Note** *This only works for MySQL 5.0 and later. It will not work for the OP's version 3.23. but I'm leaving the answer for future visitors.*

This information is available in the `information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` table.

```
USE information_schema;

SELECT
 CONSTRAINT_NAME,
 TABLE_CATALOG, 
 TABLE_NAME, 
 COLUMN_NAME, 
 REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, 
 REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  TABLE_NAME='yourtable' 
  AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='yourdatabase'
  -- For FK's only...
  AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: THANX FOR YOUR REPLY. BUT I AM AFRAID THIS DOES NOT WORK. I DON'T HAVE A DATABSE NAMED information_schema. hence use information_schema does not work. i am using mysql 3.23.54. PLEASE THROW SOME LIGHT.

Comment: ok...then there is something else that you may perhaps help me with. i have installed rhl 9 on vmware workstation ace edition. on this rhl 9 i have mysql 3.23.54a-11. i would like to upgrade this mysql3.23.54a-11 to mysql 5.0. can you suggest a way of doing this step by step. i am unable to connect to the internet using my rhl 9 running on VMware. is there a way to download the rpm for mysql 5.0 and then simply upgrade by installing that rpm package...?

Comment: @user980153 RH9 is so very many years out of date, it is no longer supported. Unless it is not an option to upgrade the OS, you really should upgrade to RHEL6 (paid support), or CentOS6 (free).  I doubt you'll be able to run MySQL5 on an 8 year old Linux distribution due to library incompatibilities.